# How to get a PDF which converts an already drawn sample to uniform

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, density-function

Suppose i have a large data pool with a particular PDF, $F(x)$, interval $[x,y]$ estimated from KDE of the datapool. I drew $N$ samples at random from that data pool and saw that their distribution is also represented quite well by $F(x)$. let this draw be $D_{bef}\sim F(x)$

Now I want another distribution $G(x)$, on same interval, such that, if i draw another $N$ sample from $G(x)$, $D_{aft}\sim G(x)$, then total $2N$ samples follow $(D_{bef} + D_{aft}) \sim Uniform(x)$.

Is it possible?? A lot of questions here want to generate uniform from PDF, but I want to draw from a PDF which when combined with my original draw, will convert them uniform.

Comment: I do not understand the question: what is the meaning of the interval $[x,y]$? What is the role of $N$? How do you get $2N$ samples $D_{bef}+D_{aft}$? What is the meaning of Uniform$(x)$ and is this $x$ related with the $x$ in $[x,y]$? What is the connection between the title of the question and the contents of the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not always possible: suppose that $F$ samples almost entirely from a subinterval $[a,b]$.  The combined sample will be almost 50% from that subinterval, so if $b-a <\frac{1}{2}(y-x)$ you can't get uniformity on $[x-y]$.

This shows what you need: for every subset of $[x,y]$, $F$ must put no more than twice as much probability on it than the uniform distribution does. That is,
you need the density $f(s)$ of $F$ to  be less than twice the uniform density $1/(y-x)$ everywhere on the interval.  You can then sample from the distribution $G$ with density
$$g(s) = \frac{2}{y-x}-f(s)$$
to get up to uniformity.

Comment: Thank you. That was informative. I understood the limitation of uniform and sampling bias as you said. Suppose if I remove the $N$ new samples limit, and say that the new pdf $G$ shall approach uniform as N approaches infinity, will that change the answer?

Comment: If the second round can  go to $\infty$ then you can handle any $F$ that has a density.  But if the interval is [0,1] and $F$ is the Bernoulli CDF you are still out of luck.